# Android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.lefu.HeartRate.EcgNative.EcgIni:(I)I

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am having a project in which i have the native files. the project executes correctly. what i have to do is to use these files in another project. i have copied the files exactly in the same manner as they are the original file. i have also changed the function names and also the header file name to point the to correct class.but i am getting the above error.`    .cpp file #include

```
#include "com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative.h"
//#include "de_PEARL_PX3756_jump_EcgNative.h"


/*
 * Class:     com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative
 * Method:    EcgIni
 * Purpose:   initialize algorithm's library of ECG
 * Signature: ()I
 */

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative_TestCalTime(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz) {

    return true;
}

/*
 * Class:     com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative
 * Method:    EcgIni
 * Purpose:   initialize algorithm's library of ECG
 * Signature: ()I
 */

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative_EcgIni(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jint i) {
    ecg_init(i);
    return 1;
}

/*
 * Class:     com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative
 * Method:    EcgInserData
 * Purpose:   put ECG data to built-in buffer of algorithm's library
 * Signature: (S)I
 */

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative_EcgInserData(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jshort a) {

    return InsertData(a);
}

/*
 * Class:     com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative
 * Method:    EcgProcessData
 * Purpose:   process ECG data by algorithm
 * Parameters: b (out): improved ECG data; a (out): rhythm of the heart
 * Return :    1: Success; Others: Fail
 * Signature: ([S[S)I
 */

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_lefu_HeartRate_EcgNative_EcgProcessData(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jshortArray b, jshortArray a) {
    unsigned char heartbeat;
    jshort *pEcgdata;
    jshort *pHeartBeat;
    int ret = 0;


    pEcgdata = env->GetShortArrayElements(b, 0);
    pHeartBeat = env->GetShortArrayElements(a, 0);
    ret = ecg_hb(&heartbeat, pEcgdata);
    if (ret == 1) {
        pHeartBeat[0] = heartbeat;
    }

    env->ReleaseShortArrayElements(b, pEcgdata, 0);
    env->ReleaseShortArrayElements(a, pHeartBeat, 0);

    return ret;
}
```

`

Comment: It may seem silly to ask this, but are you sure you have generated the native library, and that this library is package in your apk ? You can check that by doing `unzip -l /path/to/your/apk`. Inside the result you should see something like `yourlibname.so`.

Comment: no as i have mentioned in the new project i have not developed i have just copied from another project to use in the current project

Comment: native code need to be compiled. This compilation produce a dynamic library `.so` that will be packahe inside the apk. Then the library need to be dynamically loaded in your java code. If it is the first time you work with native code i suggest you to read this guide. http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html